# Android Studio does not mark setOnTabSelectedListener as deprecated in my code

Tags: android

I have a **LinearLayout** inside which are 2 design support layouts namely, **TabLayout** and a **ViewPager**. These components are nesting on an AppCompatActivity with app minSdk set to 16 and targetSdk 23. I know for a fact that setOnTabSelected is deprecated and that I should use addOnTabSelectedListener instead. The problem is that Android Studio does not mark setOnTabSelected as deprecated.

I could have settled with setupWithViewPager instead but I wanted to add tabs programmatically and switch pages using the addOnTabSelectedListener.

Comment: P.S.: my appcompat and support library are updated and have the same version